# How to get my slider to remain a certain height above 1000px (Simple Slider)

Tags: css

I've been fiddling with the css of my slider (which is generated by super simple slider) but I can't get my slider to remain a consistent height when I drag my browser window smaller. What happens is the height gets scaled down proportionally as the window gets smaller. If I hit refresh on a smaller browser window, the height is correct but for some reason when I drag the window to a smaller size, it scales the slider down. Here is the code for the styling of the slider:

```
.sss {
display: block;
height: 0;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}

.ssslide {
display: none;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.ssslide img {
display: block;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
max-width: 100%;
padding: 0;
position: relative;}

.sssnext,
.sssprev {
width: 30px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
opacity: 0.1;
}

.wedding-product-slidercontainer {
max-width: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

I've tried changing the .sss position to static which initially makes it look right but yields problems. I've also tried making the height 800px for.sss and .ssslide but neither of these solutions seem to work. I can put the whole code up on codepen if you need it but I can't seem to figure out what to do.

Comment: Please start from a [mcve].

Comment: Ok. Here is the slider demo (top of the page) > http://supersimpleslider.com from the makers of the script. As you can see when you scale down the browser window, the proportions of the entire slider scale down proportionally. But if I wanted to define the height of the slider and control it, would I need to do it in the javascript or in the css? I'm thinking the .js...Here is a link to the javascript https://github.com/intllgnt/SSS/blob/master/sss/sss.js

Comment: Well, I'd suggest you to find another slider and keep away from projects which cannot maintain their own website properly.

Comment: Noted. I am exploring other options but I am curious if this is something that is simple to change or if it’s a more complicated issue. Regardless of their website maintenance, the code seems very simple and clean and super lightweight which is something I really like about it

Comment: Their code causes whole page to jump when slides change. So it cannot be considered as a good solution. And answering to your question, yes, it's possible to make slider to have fixed height with pure css.

Comment: Their website says "If your content is of different heights, SSS will animate smoothly to accommodate it." I think the jumpiness you're talking about is just the slider resizing to fit different image heights. I personally don't think their website maintenance makes much impact on whether the code is well written or not. Sure, it's more attractive and better to have a regularly maintained website/project but I think the quality of the code should be evaluated independently.

Comment: Slider causes visual problem == slider code is not very good, IMHO.